How to get rid from @PathParam("...") in sub-resource methods in JAX-RS/RESTEasy documented with openApi?
I have a following piece of code:
@RequestScoped
@Path("/parent")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParentResource implements ParentResourceDocumentation {

    private final ParentResolver parentResolver;

    @POST
    public Response create(@Valid final CreateParentRequest createParentRequest) {
    ...
    return Response.ok(result).build();
    }

    @Path("/{parentIdentifier}/items")
    public ParentItemResource handleParentItems(@PathParam("parentIdentifier") UUID parentIdentifier, @Context ResourceContext resourceContext) {
        final var parent = parentResolver.resolve(parentIdentifier);
        return resourceContext.getResource(ParentItemResource.class).setParent(parent);
    }
}

@RequestScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParentItemResource implements ParentItemResourceDocumentation {

    @Setter
    @Accessors
    private Parent parent;

  ...

    @Override // overriden because of  openapi documentation
    public Response create(@PathParam("parentIdentifier") UUID parentIdentifier, final @Valid CreateParentItemRequest createParentItemRequest) {

        final var result = createParentItemFunction.apply(parent, createParentItemRequest);

        return Response.ok(result).build();
    }

Are there any ways to get rid from @PathParam("parentIdentifier") UUID parentIdentifier in subresource method?
Thanks a lot in advance!


Does the interface have all the annotations already (@Path and @PathParam)?

The openApi interface does not have @Path annotations, but the create method defines  @PathParam("marketplaceIdentifier") final UUID marketplaceIdentifier argument
